# AVRO schema evolution adding optional column with default fails deserialization

Tags: avro

When reading through avro documentation, for example [1], I understood, that schema evolution is supported, and if I added column with specified default, it should be backwards compatible (and even forward when I remove it again). Sounds great, so I added column defined as:

```
        {
          "name": "newColumn",
          "type": ["null","string"],
          "default": null,
          "doc": "something wrong"
        }
```

and try to consumer some topic having this schema from beginning, it fails with message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:424)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at tech.allegro.schema.json2avro.converter.JsonAvroConverter.convertToJson(JsonAvroConverter.java:83)
```

to give a little bit more information. Avro schema defines one top level type, having 2 fields. String describing type of message, and union of N types. All N-1, non-modified types can be read, but one updated with optional, default-having column cannot be read. I'm not sure if this design is strictly speaking correct, but that's not the point (feel free to criticise and recommend better approach!). I'm after schema evolution, which *seems* not to be working.

Am I doing something wrong?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.4/GettingStartedGuide/schemaevolution.html#changeschema-rules

EDIT:
and if we alter type definition to:

```
"type": "string",
"default": ""
```

it still does not work and generated error is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -1
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:336)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:263)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:201)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:422)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:414)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at tech.allegro.schema.json2avro.converter.JsonAvroConverter.convertToJson(JsonAvroConverter.java:83)
```

what code does lead to given failures:

```
BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avro, (BinaryDecoder)null);
GenericRecord record = (GenericRecord)(new GenericDatumReader(schema)).read((Object)null, binaryDecoder);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is usually some miss-understanding regarding to schema evolution and how it works.   When you evolution a schema it does not mean that you don't need the "writer" schema to read the avro data. For this  purposes you should be using the following constructor [GenericDatumReader](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericDatumReader.html#GenericDatumReader(org.apache.avro.Schema,%20org.apache.avro.Schema))

```
public GenericDatumReader(Schema writer,
                  Schema reader)
```

As you can see, writer schema (schema used to serialize the avro data) and reader schema ( your "evolution" schema) must be present. There are several libraries/tools (Hive, Spark) that abstract this but it is only possible because the file itself contains the schema (non schema-less)

Comment: I must say,I 100% do not understand what you said. ~writer reading avro data??? Nevertheless my situation is this: I have reader reading the data, and writer writing the data,both using the same schema. I need to evolve schema. From that point on, writer will be writing the schema enriched with one field,while reader should be able to process both already existing messages without field in question, and also messages with that field. ||| I also use avro-maven-plugin, thus I'd like to use ...Reader, which can deserialize into avro generated classes. GenericDatumReader IIRC deserialize Object[].

Comment: You may want to read some documentation and come with specific questions, also a working example of your issue would help to give you a working code

Comment: If I upset you, I apologize. I've been searching for this answer in documentation and stackoverflow and mailing lists for more than a day. I found many users searching for answer. From that I conclude, this is not obvious task easy to find. Please could you share serializer/deserializer which can serialize/deserialize binary avro messages from/to avro generated classes and which supports schema evolution. Specific question. I don't have working code. If it is documented anywhere, please share link. Tens of people would be grateful.

Comment: I got an in-depth reply on mailing list. I'll test it and provide answer here, when I'm sure it fixed my issues, so that others can easily consume that as well.